# xamarin android error APT0000: duplicate value for resource '' with config ''

Tags: android, xamarin, build

I'm using Xamarin Android with Visual Studio. My two projects has built without errors until update visual studio and xamarin.

I get errors 
error APT0000: duplicate value for resource 'styleable/custom_button' with config ''.
error APT0000: resource previously defined here.
...

I have version 16.3.9 and xamarin android 10.0.6.2

[Project](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/files/3854394/TestApp.zip) for testing

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try remove bin/ and obj/ folders in your projects. Also make sure that stylable isn't duplicated.

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> APT0000: duplicate value for resource 'styleable/custom_button' with config ''. error APT0000: resource previously defined here

[image]
The error is caused on the same name in `declare-styleable`. Double click the error, you could open the `attrs.xml` file.

```
<declare-styleable name="custom_button">
<attr name="id_expandable_layout" format="reference"/>
</declare-styleable>
<declare-styleable name="custom_button">
<attr name="ascbackground" format="reference"/>
```

**Solution:**
You could change the name. Use the different name, it will be okay.

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works, but i dont understand why it works before update vs and xamarin, but after update not works